# VBA Search Range for text then run macro

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a VBA macro (which I'll attach to a command button) which searches K7 through K13 to find "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", or "Sheet4" Only one answer is possible based on pre-existing If/Then statements. 
When it finds "Sheet1" I want it to run macro "GoToSheet1"
When it finds "Sheet2" I want it to run macro "GoToSheet2"
When it finds "Sheet3" I want it to run macro "GoToSheet3"
When it finds "Sheet4" I want it to run macro "GoToSheet4"

Basically i have four possible conditions which could exist based on how someone answers two yes/no questions. That is what the initial if/then statements cover. However, I cannot get the VBA macro to search across the cell range K7 through K13 for any one of the four text phrases.

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far?

Comment: Try `If Not Range("K7:K13").Find("Sheet1") Is Nothing Then GoToSheet1`

Comment: I tried Case Statements using existing forum examples, but am not sure how to change the search from a cell to a range. I'm also not sure how to get multiple outcomes (for example if it doesn't find "Sheet1" then i want it to search for "Sheet2").

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$K$7" Then

Select Case Target.Value

Case "Sheet1"
Call GoToSheet1

Case "Sheet2"
Call GoToSheet2

Case "Sheet3"
Call GoToSheet3

Case "Sheet4"
Call GoToSheet4

End Select

End If

End Sub


This is obviously wrong because it only searches a specific cell "K7" not the range "K7" to "K13"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely you can loop thru the range `K7:K13` for checking each cell values. However using `Range.Find` method would be a better way to do this.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim lookingRange As Range
    Set lookingRange = Range("K7:K13")
    If Not lookingRange.Find(What:="Sheet1", LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then GoToSheet1: Exit Sub
    If Not lookingRange.Find(What:="Sheet2", LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then GoToSheet2: Exit Sub
    If Not lookingRange.Find(What:="Sheet3", LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then GoToSheet3: Exit Sub
    If Not lookingRange.Find(What:="Sheet4", LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then GoToSheet4: Exit Sub
    MsgBox "not found"
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks @newacc2240, how could I write this so that it searches the cell values and not the formulas in it?

Comment: Edited. However my excel searches the cell values by default, weird.

Comment: GOLDEN! Much appreciated!